# Установка сайта на yii2 локально

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, yii, composer

Всем привет, пришло мне ТЗ: *"Развернуть сайт локально на yii2"*. Я скачал все файлы сайта через FTP на жесткий диск и закинул в папку htdocs (использую MAMP). Настроил сервер, виртуальные хосты и т.д. Перехожу в папку и дальше не знаю что делать, потому что с yii2 сталкиваюсь впервые.

Сначала была проблема с фалом htaccess (Файл был сохранен в кодировке UTF-8 With BOM), еле еле допер сохранить в кодировке UTF-8, чтобы убрать ошибку: **Internal Server Error**

Затем выходит **An internal server error occurred.**, мне посоветовали переустановить папку vendor со всеми зависимостями.

Удаляю папку **/vendor**, устанавливаю **compose**r на компьютер, перехожу в папку проекта и запускаю

```
composer install
```

Выходит ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую запустить

```
composer update
```

Снова ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зашел в файл composer.json

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "leandrogehlen/yii2-treegrid": "*",
    "yiidoc/yii2-redactor": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "~2.0.0",
    "2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget": "~1.0",
    "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "*",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "3.*",
    "himiklab/yii2-sitemap-module" : "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
    "omnilight/yii2-scheduling": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

}

И увидел что там вместо версий стоят *. Я не понимаю, может в этом дело? Проблему решает команда и все пакеты устанавливаются:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Но снова выходит **An internal server error occurred.** Думаю что еще что-то надо настраивать? Подскажите, может в самих файлах надо что то прописывать? Типо php init и т.д.?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: откатите composer.lock, и ещё раз попробуйте composer install

Comment: Для таких вещей надо использовать нормальную платформу, например OpenServer